# Integrating with RealVNC Client

Tags: delphi, winapi, delphi-2010

I'm doing a project for automatic login thru Real VNC client. I have a LAN and have been boring do such procedures with this client in many pcs. So I decided automatize the process. I open the VNC client with my program (using CreateProcess), and passing the IP for connecting as parameter. My intention now is send the password for that machine and simulate [enter], and i'm stuck into this step. I'll explain better with the code below:

```
procedure TForm1.VncAuth;
var
  StartInfo: TStartupInfo;
  ProcInfo: TProcessInformation;
  CmdLine: string;
begin
  FillChar(StartInfo,SizeOf(TStartupInfo),#0);
  FillChar(ProcInfo,SizeOf(TProcessInformation),#0);
  StartInfo.cb := SizeOf(TStartupInfo);
  CmdLine:= 'vnc.exe 192.168.1.14';
  UniqueString(CmdLine);
  CreateProcess(NIL ,PChar(CmdLine), NIL, NIL, False, CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE or NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS
                                  , NIL, NIL, StartInfo, ProcInfo);
  WaitForInputIdle(ProcInfo.hProcess, INFINITE);
  Timer:= TTimer.Create(Nil);
  Timer.Interval:= 5000;
  Timer.OnTimer:= DoVNCAuth;
  Timer.Enabled:= true;
end;
```

Ok, the procedure above open the vnc.exe and pass the IP for connection. So I wait 5 seconds, time to connect into IP and vnc ask for password, after 5 secs I go to procedure DoVNCAuth. It's like this:

```
procedure TForm1.DoVNCAuth(Sender: TObject);
var
  pass: string;
begin
  pass:= 'password';
  VNCChild:= FindWindowEx(0, 0, Nil, 'VNC Viewer - Authentication');
  if VNCChild > 0 then
    begin
      VNCHandle:= FindWindowEx(VNCChild, 0, 'Edit', 0);
      SendMessage(VNCHandle, WM_SETTEXT, 0, Integer(PChar(pass)));
    end;
end;
```

This procedure, search for the window asking for vnc auth. So I search for Edit inside the window and send my password. The problem is: this window have 2 edits, one for user (disabled) and one for pass (this is my focus), but I can only write my pass into user's edit. How to get the handle for the right edit? They are into same window and are from same class 'Edit'... Below a screenshot of what happens:
[image]

Comment: Chances are that your Real VNC client is not a Delphi application and the dialog is based on a resource. Then you can use GetDlgItem on the top-level window ('VNC Viewer - Authentication').

Comment: .. failing that, you can probably differentiate the edits with the ES_PASSWORD style, failing that, you can compare screen positions of the two edits..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making it far harder than it needs to be. RealVNC already comes equipped with features that allow you to connect without requiring interaction. All you need to do is create a text file containing the necessary options and pass that to the RealVNC viewer program on startup.

The text file might look like this:

```
[Connection]
Host=myhost.com::666
Encryption=AlwaysOn
Username=domain\user
Password=********
[Options]
....
```

You can get RealVNC to create the file for you by opening the connection, bringing up the RealVNC menu (i.e. with F8), and then selecting **Save Connection**. This will save a .vnc file containing all the settings of that connection. Just pass that .vnc file to the viewer program on startup and it's all good.

All you need to do therefore is:

1. Create the .vnc connection files.
2. Change the command line to `'vnc.exe connection.vnc'`.
3. Remove all the code after the call to `CreateProcess`.
4. Call `CloseHandle` on the two handles returned by `CreateProcess`.

For your needs I suggest that calling `ShellExecute` is probably easier than `CreateProcess`.

Comment: Yes I got your point... I can work this way, but I need to know how the hash for password in .vnc file is created... So I can create .vnc files automatically for new passwords. Do you have any reference in Delphi that how it is generated?

Comment: I don't know. You can look at the VNC source. Or send an e-mail to the RealVNC people. I had not imagined that you'd want to generate passwords too.

Comment: Yes in fact I didn't was looking for this, but with your solution, I'll need it... Anyway is a smart solution. I'll do some research and post here...

Comment: I'd be interested to hear what you find!

Comment: I just found a working library to crypt DES (same as VNC does), and it's working now. I accepted your answer as solution! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I made an UltraVnc dll (from original c++ sources) for both server and client.
Maybe this can help you? 
http://code.google.com/p/asmprofiler/source/browse/trunk/-Other-/UltraVnc+As+Dll/?r=294

Comment: Thank you. I'll check later, but I'm more into David Heffernan answer. Just doing some researchs about how to encrypt the pass same way as VNC does. Almost there!